# Mysql INTO OUTFILE nested unions with NULL causing a formatting issue with integer

Tags: mysql, union, redhat, myisam, into-outfile

I have strange behavior with *SELECT INTO OUFILE* and I didn't find an answer.

To resume I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `field1` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `field2` int(11) default NULL,
  `field3` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When I execute a query like this :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.dat' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM mytable;
```

I obtain a result like this in the output.dat :

```
"12345678"|"20.00^@^@^@^@^@^@^@"|"1426513906^@"|"0^@^@^@"
"95863214"|"20.00^@^@^@^@^@^@^@"|"1426514075^@"|"1^@^@^@"
```

without *ESCAPED BY* :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.dat' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM mytable;
```

I have a result like this :

```
"12345678"|"20.00\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"|"1426513906\0"|"0\0\0\0"
"95863214"|"20.00\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"|"1426514075\0"|"1\0\0\0"
```

Mysql environment:

```
"protocol_version";"10"
"version";"5.0.67-community-log"
"version_comment";"MySQL Community Edition (GPL)"
"version_compile_machine";"x86_64"
"version_compile_os";"redhat-linux-gnu"
```

It seem like mysql try to fill with this special characters to have the size set in the structure of mytble. With *TRIM* I don't have this characters. But I want to know if it's normal to have this behavior only with integer and decimal or it's bug ? I want to know also if there are another solution to avoid using *TRIM* with each field ? Because I have a lot of queries more complex then this one.

Thank you for your help and the time that you took to read my post

Regards

**EDIT:** I thought that the problem probably comes from *INTO OUFILE* and type fields only. I didn't think to mention nested unions in this case. So I changed the title and I'm responding to my question.

Comment: It's not the reason. But you pointed on a mistake that I have made when I wrote this post. I copied/pasted the wrong query. Now, it's the right one. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Okay, still just FYI, I can not reproduce this behaviour with 5.6.20. And I do not remember to ever have had this behaviour with prior versions. How do you view the result? Maybe it's not a MySQL issue, but your editor / shell.

Comment: I'm using linux editor vi. It's not the editor. I have warnings like "_Data truncated for column 'field1' at row 1_" on this when I try to load this kind of data. 

Edit: I just noticed that, I don't have this behavior with the primary key! Strange!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Last EDIT :** **To resume**, the best solution found is to force **escape** with backslash and **not leave it empty** :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output1.dat' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM 
    ((SELECT
    id_test,
    field2,
    field3
    FROM mytable1)

    UNION

    (SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
        ((SELECT
        id_test,
        field2,
        NULL AS field3
        FROM mytable2)

        UNION

        (SELECT
        id_test,
        NULL AS field2,
        NULL AS field3
        FROM mytable3)
        ) test)
    ) tmptable;
```

**Notes from [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) :**

> If the FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is empty, no characters are escaped
>   and NULL is output as NULL, not \N. It is probably not a good idea to
>   specify an empty escape character, particularly if field values in
>   your data contain any of the characters in the list just given.
>
> ....
>
> Also note that if you specify an empty ESCAPED BY value, it is
>   possible to inadvertently generate output that cannot be read properly
>   by LOAD DATA INFILE.

**Previous solutions with explanation :**

I found the answer to my problem.
It's come from the nested unions with NULL values. I'll explain with example it's better than long speach.

Here the mysql context :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable1`;

CREATE TABLE `mytable1` (
  `id_test` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_test`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=95863215 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `mytable` */

INSERT  INTO `mytable1`(`id_test`,`field1`,`field2`,`field3`) VALUES (12345678,20.00,1426513906,0),(95863214,20.00,1426514075,1);

/*Table structure for table `mytable2` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable2`;

CREATE TABLE `mytable2` (
  `id_test` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_test`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `mytable2` */

INSERT  INTO `mytable2`(`id_test`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1,25.00,12345),(2,11.00,52146);

/*Table structure for table `mytable3` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable3`;

CREATE TABLE `mytable3` (
  `id_test` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_test`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `mytable3` */

INSERT  INTO `mytable3`(`id_test`,`field1`,`field3`) VALUES (2,12.00,2),(4,23.00,31);
```

And with environment :

```
"protocol_version";"10"
"version";"5.0.67-community-log"
"version_comment";"MySQL Community Edition (GPL)"
"version_compile_machine";"x86_64"
"version_compile_os";"redhat-linux-gnu"
```

Or with this one :

```
"protocol_version";"10"
"version";"5.0.95-log"
"version_bdb";"Sleepycat Software: Berkeley DB 4.1.24: (December 16, 2011)"
"version_comment";"Source distribution"
"version_compile_machine";"x86_64"
"version_compile_os";"redhat-linux-gnu"
```

We reproduce the case with this kind of query :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output1.dat' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM 
    ((SELECT
    id_test,
    field2,
    field3
    FROM mytable1)

    UNION

    (SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
        ((SELECT
        id_test,
        field2,
        NULL AS field3
        FROM mytable2)

        UNION

        (SELECT
        id_test,
        NULL AS field2,
        NULL AS field3
        FROM mytable3)
        ) test)
    ) tmptable;
```

We obtain this result :

```
"12345678"|"1426513906"|"0^@^@^@"
"95863214"|"1426514075"|"1^@^@^@"
"1"|"12345"|NULL
"2"|"52146"|NULL
"2"|NULL|NULL
"4"|NULL|NULL
```

When we execute the same query with replacing the last NULL with 1 for example or with removing the last union :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output1.dat' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM 
    ((SELECT
    id_test,
    field2,
    field3
    FROM mytable1)

    UNION

    (SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
        ((SELECT
        id_test,
        field2,
        NULL AS field3
        FROM mytable2)

        UNION

        (SELECT
        id_test,
        NULL AS field2,
        1 AS field3
        FROM mytable3)
        ) test)
    ) tmptable;
```

We obtain the expected rigth result :

```
"12345678"|"1426513906"|"0"
"95863214"|"1426514075"|"1"
"1"|"12345"|NULL
"2"|"52146"|NULL
"2"|NULL|1
"4"|NULL|1
```

This is just a simple example without *WHERE* to explain. In my case, the nested union is used because we have different values in different conditions.

So be careful with nested *UNION* with *NULL* values in the case of export with *INTO OUTFILE*. For my case the solution was the fuse nested unions in one query without *UNION*.

Note that I didn't reproduce this case with Mysql 5.6.23 MySQL Community Server on Windows 7.